# RabbitMQ doesn't retrieve messages after resetting OnMessageReceived

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ.Client(C#) to work with RabbitMQ. I am having trouble retrieving the messages from the queue once I remove and re-add the message received event handler. 
`consumer.Received -= OnMessageRecieved;`
I have a complex system, where a windows service subscribes to the RabbitMQ queues and process the messages. There are multiple threads running for various things - timer to call PUSH api, another timer to do api authentication etc. If api authentication fails, we don't want to process the messages from the queue. We want to keep the messages in ready state. Only, when the api authentication is success, we want to process the messages. So, on failure event, we remove the event handler and on success we add it back. When we do that, the event handler is added successfully, but now the messages are not retrieved from the queue.

To simulate this, I have created a console app. I have written this in less than an hour, I know this code is very raw and dirty - please excuse me for that. 
`sub.StopReceiveMessages();` has the code that removes handler `consumer.Received -= OnMessageRecieved`. And, `sub.StartReceiveMessages();` has the code that removes handler `consumer.Received += OnMessageRecieved`. When you add it back I thought it would work as normal. But, it doesn't hit the `MessageReceived()` anymore. Is it that we have to call BasicConsume again although I am using the same consumer? Any help would be appreciate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Client = RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace RabbitMQTest
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBusSubscription sub = new MessageBusSubscription();

            sub.Subscription("EmployeeDataChanged", "HR", "CompanyA", 5, 5000);
            sub.MessagesReceived += MessageReceived;
            Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to exit");
            while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
            {
                // Simulating an event where we have to stop pulling the messages from the queue
                sub.StopReceiveMessages();

                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                // After some time, the issue is resolved and now we resume reading the messages from the queue
                sub.StartReceiveMessages();
            }
            sub.Dispose();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private static bool MessageReceived(string topic, string subscription, List<MessageContainer> messages)
        {
            List<MessageContainer> data = null;
            data = messages as List<MessageContainer>;

            foreach (var messageContainer in data)
            {
                // Do something with the message
                // Ack or Reject based on some logic
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
    public class MessageBusSubscription : IDisposable
    {
        #region variables
        Client.Events.EventingBasicConsumer consumer;
        Client.ConnectionFactory factory;        
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer = null;
        private Client.IModel _channel = null;
        private string _topic = string.Empty;
        private string _subscription = string.Empty;
        int batchCounter = 0;
        int batchSize = 0;
        ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        bool _disposing = false;
        bool _isSubscribed = false;
        List<MessageContainer> messages = new List<MessageContainer>();
        private object _processMessageLocker = new object();
        public event Func<string, string, List<MessageContainer>, bool> MessagesReceived;
        #endregion
        public MessageBusSubscription()
        {
            Client.IConnection conn = GetConnection();
            _channel = conn.CreateModel();
        }
        public void Subscription(string exchangeName, string queueName, string routingKey, int batchSize, double batchInterval)
        {
            _topic = exchangeName;
            _subscription = queueName;
            DeclareExchangeAndQueue(exchangeName, queueName, routingKey);

            if (batchInterval > 0 && batchSize > 1)
            {
                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(batchInterval);

                _timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => {
                    ProcessMessagesReceived(exchangeName, queueName, true);
                };
            }
            Subscribe(routingKey, exchangeName, queueName, batchSize, batchInterval);
        }
        public Task Subscribe(string routingKey, string topic, string subscription, int _batchSize, double batchInterval)
        {
            try
            {
                consumer = new Client.Events.EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

                batchCounter = 0;
                batchSize = _batchSize;

                consumer.Received += OnMessageRecieved;
                _isSubscribed = true;

                //RabbitMQ PUSH implementation using RabbitMQ.Client library
                var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (_timer != null)
                        {
                            _timer.Start();
                        }

                        var queueName = string.Join(".", routingKey, topic, subscription);

                        if (!_disposing)
                        {
                            _channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
                            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
                        }

                        if (_timer != null)
                        {
                            _timer.Stop();
                            _timer.Dispose();
                        }

                        if (_channel != null)
                        {
                            if (_channel.IsOpen)
                                _channel.Close();
                            _channel.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                });

                return t;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var exTask = new Task(() => { throw new AggregateException(ex); });
                exTask.RunSynchronously();
                return exTask;
            }
        }
        public void OnMessageRecieved(Client.IBasicConsumer sender, Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string sourceExchange = string.Empty;
                string sourceQueue = string.Empty;

                string body = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body);
                string routingKey = e.RoutingKey;
                ulong deliveryTag = e.DeliveryTag;
                sourceExchange = "";
                sourceQueue = "";
                MessageContainer msgContainer = new MessageContainer();
                msgContainer.Message = body;

                batchCounter++;
                msgContainer.DeliveryTag = deliveryTag;

                lock (_processMessageLocker)
                {
                    messages.Add(msgContainer);
                    ProcessMessagesReceived(_topic, _subscription, false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
        public void ProcessMessagesReceived(string topic, string subscription, bool hasTimerElapsed)
        {
            try
            {
                // if it's the last message in the batch, or the interval has elapsed
                if ((batchCounter % batchSize == 0 && messages.Count > 0) || (hasTimerElapsed && messages.Count > 0))
                {
                    if (_timer != null)
                    {
                        _timer.Stop();
                    }

                    lock (_processMessageLocker)
                    {
                        // process the message
                        if (!MessagesReceived(topic, subscription, messages))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Message processing exception - look in the default error queue (broker)");
                        }
                        messages.Clear();
                    }

                    batchCounter = 0;
                    if (_timer != null)
                    {
                        _timer.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        public Client.IConnection GetConnection()
        {
            factory = new Client.ConnectionFactory();

            factory.UserName = "guest";
            factory.Password = "guest";
            factory.VirtualHost = "/";
            factory.HostName = "localhost";
            factory.Protocol = Client.Protocols.AMQP_0_9_1;
            factory.Port = 5673;

            return factory.CreateConnection();
        }
        public void DeclareExchangeAndQueue(string exchangeName, string queueName, string routingKey)
        {
            using (var exchangeConn = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (Client.IModel channel = exchangeConn.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, Client.ExchangeType.Direct);

                var queue = String.Join(".", routingKey, exchangeName, queueName);
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
                channel.QueueBind(queue, exchangeName, routingKey, null);
            }
        }
        public void StartReceiveMessages()
        {
            if (_timer != null && !_isSubscribed)
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }

            if (consumer != null && !_isSubscribed)
            {
                consumer.Received += OnMessageRecieved;
                _isSubscribed = true;
            }            
        }
        public void StopReceiveMessages()
        {
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
            }

            if (consumer != null)
            {
                consumer.Received -= OnMessageRecieved;
                _isSubscribed = false;
            }                        
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _disposing = true;
            _waitHandle.Set();
            _waitHandle?.Dispose();
            _waitHandle = null;

            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                _timer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    public class MessageContainer
    {
        public ulong DeliveryTag { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't unsubscribe from the `Received` event, instead use the `BasicCancel` method to stop consuming messages, then use `BasicConsume` again to start consuming.

A lot of the thread synchronization code as well as running the consumer in a `Task` isn't really the best practice. If you'd like further assistance with this code, save it in a git repository or gist somewhere and follow-up on the official mailing list.